# Scan entire process memory with ReadProcessMemory

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm tryin to scan an entire process memory but no success... What I'm doing is: for tests I'm using notepad, so I write there **%B** and this values in HEX are: 25(%) and 42(B). So the code is:

```
  while (VirtualQueryEx(PIDHandle, Pointer(MemStart), MemInfo, SizeOf(MemInfo)) <> 0) do
    begin
      if ((MemInfo.State = MEM_COMMIT) and (not (MemInfo.Protect = PAGE_GUARD)
        or (MemInfo.Protect = PAGE_NOACCESS)) and (MemInfo.Protect = PAGE_READWRITE)) then
          begin
            SetLength(Buff, MemInfo.RegionSize);
              if (ReadProcessMemory(PIDHandle, MemInfo.BaseAddress, Buff,
                                        MemInfo.RegionSize, ReceivedBytes)) then
                begin
                for I := 0 to SizeOf(Buff) do
                 begin
   if (IntToHex(Buff[i], 1) = '25') and (IntToHex(Buff[i+2], 1) = '42') then
                  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Append(IntToHex(Buff[i], 1));
                 end;

                end;
          end;
      MemStart:= MemStart + MemInfo.RegionSize;
    end;
  CloseHandle(PIDHandle);
  end;
```

The var 'Buff' is TBytes (I read about TBytes and think it's same as array of byte). So I'm converting the bytes to Hex, and searching for values: 25 and 42 respectively. The code is like:

```
if (IntToHex(Buff[i], 1) = '25') and (IntToHex(Buff[i+2], 1) = '42') then
```

Because have 00 between the hex values. So I need to add '+2'. How can I scan the entire memory for this values??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notepad uses Unicode so you'll need to look for UTF-16 encoded data, `$0025` and `$0042`.

I don't understand why you feel the need to convert into hex strings before comparing. There's nothing special about hex that requires the use of strings. Hexadecimal is just a number system with base-16. So, decimal 32 is the same as hexadecimal 20, i.e. `32=$20`. Do your comparison directly with integral values:

```
if (Buff[i]=$25) and (Buff[i+2]=$42) then
```

That said, taking into account the `$00` bytes your test should really be something like this:

```
var
  Target: string;
....
Target := '%B';
if CompareMem(@Buff[i], @Target[1], Length(Target)*SizeOf(Char)) then
  ....
```

I don't want to get too deep into the rest of your code, but this line

```
for I := 0 to SizeOf(Buff) do
```

is wrong on many different levels.

1. `SizeOf(Buff)` returns the size of a pointer since a dynamic array variable is essentially just a pointer. A useful thing to remember is that `SizeOf` is evaluated at compile time.
2. If you used `Length` instead of `SizeOf` then you would be iterating over the end of the list. To loop over a dynamic array, loop from `0` to `Length(...)-1`.
3. But in this case you are accessing index `i+2` inside the loop, so you should loop from `0` to `Length(...)-3`.

But in fact you need to compare against 4 consecutive bytes to find a match. Perhaps like this:

```
TargetByteLength = Length(Target)*SizeOf(Char);
for i := 0 to Length(Buff)-TargetByteLength do
  if CompareMem(@Buff[i], @Target[1], TargetByteLength) then
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and attention. But still a mistery for me why the program can't find the values inside the notepad's memory. If I use the ReadProcessMemory like:
ReadProcessMemory(PIDHandle, Pointer($00367ED0), Buff,MemInfo.RegionSize, ReceivedBytes), with the right address pointer, it find. But scanning the entire memory, don't find anything. Sorry for the incovenience...